# Jquery Sticky Plugin broken on Mobile browser

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-mobile, mobile-browser

I recently adapted the jQuery plugin, 'Sticky,' for my companies WordPress site. The plugin itself is strictly jQuery, and not WordPress specific. While the plugin works great for desktop browsers, it's having styling troubles when rendered on mobile.

How do I get the page to discern the difference between a mobile and desktop browser, then execute code specific to the browser?

The webpage in question is: http://www.energytoolsint.com/who-we-are/

Comment: Please don't expect users to reverse-engineer your page. Post the relevant code in your question.

Comment: Check-out the mobile browser support for `position:fixed`, it's spotty until you get to newish OSes: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-fixed